# Why are 5 close votes required?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Why are 5 close votes required? Who picked this?

Why not 3 or 4? Why not 6? Is there empirical evidence that 5 is the correct number? Put another way, would changing the number of close votes to say, 4, alter the number of incorrectly closed posts? What would be the effect of the change?

Comment: As for "recent efforts", I *think* things are being done in [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to organize some kind of close events.

Comment: The only constant source of pain from the CV queue is from people mistakenly fixating on the size of it. The same people are usually quick to turn around and complain about the decreasing quality of questions. They complain about quality, then they complain about the size of the CV queue.... which got that way by people voting to close low quality posts.

Comment: The size of the CV queue is going up and down based on a number of variables. It's actual size is rather inconsequential - until next mod elections and you'll get 2 dozen people promising to reduce it to zero.

Comment: If everybody would do what you did once you reached the 3K reputation and got the vote to close privilege. Handle all the for you available review tasks. Remember to filter on tags you have knowledge off and as suggested by @user3580294, pay a visit to our chat room to drop a message how you're doing. Not meant for you but for all other readers: **Use your daily allotted review tasks!**

Comment: This question is actually two reasonably unrelated questions. Can it be split up? I think it should be fairly easy to reword the first question into a non opinion-based one...

Comment: @Andy - out of curiosity, why was this question down voted so much? What is so offensive about it? I landed here because I was interested in the the same things - understanding where 5 came from, empirical evidence on the magic number, reasoning and motivation, etc. (Its not an agree/disagree suggestion, so that would not explain the down votes).

Comment: @jww I had originally asked a second part to my original question that broadened the question far too much. My question was subsequently closed (ironic), so I changed it. When re-opened all the downvotes remain - as well as the negative stigma associated with them. This is another question I intend to research / ask in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When [close voting was first introduced in December 2008](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/i-move-to-close-this-question/), three votes were required:

> Allowing a single person with 3,000 rep to close a question isn’t really in the spirit of having a consensus that SO was founded on. It’s true that a peer can then come along and reopen the question at will any time, but this then leads to ping-pong battles of opening and closing between two users. And probably a lot of angst...

**If three people agree that a question should be closed** (for any reason), it will be closed. If you disagree with this, no problem! You can reopen the question in the very same way...

> 

If three users with 3,000+ rep all **vote to reopen a question**, it will be reopened...

My understanding is, as site scaled up and more questions and voters entered the system, three turned out insufficient (maybe because of *close-reopen wars*).

FWIW, it took only a year or less to get from 3 to 5, as can be seen from [August 2009 meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11597/165773):

> ...**it takes 5 votes to close**...

Should the number of votes to close be reduced from it's current number or would we just get back into close wars...

> 

SO scaled up close votes required as the number of people who can vote to close increased.

---

Since you [also asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/261746/1) about *recent efforts in Close Votes queue*, most notable and promising as of "June 2014" is definitely...

#### [bootstrapping of the Anti-Recidivism System](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/165773)

This system is intended to cut the close vote queue "from the other end", that is to substantially limit amount of close-worthy questions posted at Stack Overflow, by making it harder for help vampires to dump their garbage at us.

> It's important to clarify, we're improving question blocks substantially...

What does this get us?

> 

People that treat questions as a resource that *can* be depleted, who learn how to ask questions *only* when they really need to and make them *count* when they do. Or, they keep throwing themselves at the wall and then get stuck in the mean hairy algorithm (Jeff wrote that, so it's intentionally both mean and hairy, I assure you - just the meanest hairiest tough-love you ever saw).

> 

...result should be, those that *can* be helped are helped, those that *can't* get stuck in the room with the big, mean hairy algorithm, and *deleting your account no longer helps*...

Comment: Might want to check the date on that blog post you're citing in the first paragraph...

Comment: @Shog9 thanks! Corrected: "12-31-08" in blog date means December not August (guess I read that "08" twice, once as a year, another as a month)

Comment: I remember the thread that caused the vote count to increase... I don't remember the details, I just remember being involved in it... It went back and forth, open and close for days until Jeff finally upped it to 4.. and it still kept going... then he upped it to 5... and it eventually stopped.  3 is a bit too small a number for a membership the size of SO, as all it takes is 3 contrarians and a different 3 contrarians (guilty as charged) to make it annoying for everyone.

Comment: a bit of even more ancient history: per [recollection of a particular old-timer at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20626/165773), "Back in November of '08, it only took a single user (with at or above 3K reputation) to close a question. And users with considerably less reputation could close _their own_ questions..."