# Why does it require 3k rep to go on the close review queue?

Tags: discussion, reputation, vote-to-close

The question is pretty well described by the title.  There are more then ten thousand close votes in the queue so why is the minimum rep set to 3k?  Was it an arbitrary decision?  Or is there some highly logical reason for having things set up the way they are?

What would be the downsides to lowering the rep requirement and allowing close votes to be reviewed quicker or what upsides are there to raising the rep requirement and making close votes have to wait longer to be reviewed?

Edit: I a not looking for answers like "that's the point when you're trusted".  I am curious about how SE arrived at 3k and not 3.5k or 2.5k or even 10k or 1k.

Comment: Crystal ball. The same reason a dollar equals 100 cent and not 20 or 200. 3k is just easier to remember and write than 2.994k

Comment: I think the idea is that at lower rep questions would be instantly closed only to be instantly reopened. As less people have the higher rep, less of a close/reopen war.

Comment: @randomusername: for the same reason most thresholds are set, because it seemed about right when they set it. Could be drifted slowly with A/B testing in an automated fashion...

Comment: +1 I don't see the point of having a close review queue with thousands of items.

Comment: I agree - it does seem a little arbitrary. On Literature SE I got close vote rights at 500 reputation - that's probably really low for a mature site (Lit SE is still in public beta), but it's not 3K across all sites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What would be the downsides to lowering the rep requirement and allowing close votes to be reviewed quicker or what upsides are there to raising the rep requirement and making close votes have to wait longer to be reviewed?

The downsides of lowering:

- the lower the reputation threshold you set for this, the lower the reviewer's investment is in the site. The average user has written 81 posts at 1K and 209 by 3K - that's a fair bit of extra involvement, and conceptually a larger "ownership" of the site. We'd like it if the folks voting to close or reopen here were doing so out of a desire to keep up the site that *they helped build*...
- the lower the reputation threshold you set, the less *time* your average user will have spent on the site. If you haven't been around very much, how are you supposed to even *know* what sorts of problems we're looking to avoid? I gotta be honest: 3K isn't the best test for this, and some folks get the privilege without anywhere *near* enough experience - but lowering it further isn't gonna help.

The upsides of raising:

- More investment
- More experience
- More pent-up rage (possibly not an upside)

Answer (score 5):

You need 3k rep to use the close vote queue because it takes 3k rep to vote to close questions.  There wouldn't be much use in having access to the queue if you don't have the ability to vote to close questions.

Comment: But why do you need 3k rep to vote to close?

Comment: @randomusername It's the point at which the system trusts you enough to feel confident in your ability to know whether or not a question should be closed.

Comment: @randomusername - just because. I'd guess SE folks decided that by the time one gains 3K rep most of "rage close/editing" urges are gone and user seen enough of good/bad questions to start closing question...

Comment: I wonder if it would make sense to allow people below 3K to review, with the only options being to "leave open" or "skip".

Comment: @randomusername: because you need a minimum amount of trust and experience with the site before you can close.

Comment: @user000001 In order to vote to leave questions open they'd need to know which questions should be closed.

Comment: @randomusername decision about 3K rep was made in stone age times, [when closing was first introduced in August 2008](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261757/839601)

Comment: @gnat That's the kind of answer I was looking for, but was there anything else that contributed deciding on 3k rep as the minimum?

Answer (score 1):

The whole rep/privileges thing is a bit arbitrary. I guess the founders of SO and their helpers just liked simple numbers. And since it is all a bit arbitrary, why not 3k. It's roughly the point where someone can be trusted. Personally I would be happy with any other number in that range as well. It doesn't really matter because it is not that important.