# Why did my question receive a close vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Concerning the following question: [Is using variants in vba bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939826/is-using-variants-in-vba-bad-for-performance)

My question received a close vote due to it being too broad. In my opinion, the question was rather straightforward. In it's most basic form, I wanted a yes or a no. Why did someone view this question as too broad, and how can I prevent this in the future?

Comment: Why do you bring this up for just a single close vote?

Comment: It seems that at least someone perceived this question badly, and I don't like that!

Comment: Because the user who voted thinks the question is too broad. And I can kinda get that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are 5 close votes required?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261746/why-are-5-close-votes-required)

Comment: It has _only_ gotten 1 close vote. That happens. Don't worry about it. Now, by posting about this, you're attracting a lot more viewers to that question, which can possibly result in more close votes. (That's called the ["Meta effect"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect))

Comment: It's broad (not neccessarily _too_ broad, but broad) because it's not very specific. You don't ask a specific question with regard to a specific piece of code; you ask a general quesiton about all of the performance implications of a language feature. The answer is probably not as simple as a "yes" or "no"; and even then that isn't very useful because it does not quantify the difference and performance isn't the first priority in most cases anyways. I guess what you'd actually want to know is "when should I use / not use this" which is of course an even broader topic.

Comment: Well, you got the Yes and No answer.  Somebody tried to close it before you got a Maybe.  Which would have been the appropriate answer, but I doubt anybody had the time to write a book.  That was *not* great Q+A, closing is meant to prevent it.  That doesn't always work.  You chose the off-site resource as the answer, turning the Q+A just into a link-trap.  The core reason behind SO losing its favorite Google ranking.

Comment: Allright, well thank you all for the replies. It seems my question my question here was not well perceived, I'll see if I can do better next time..

Comment: fyi, Hans Passant's comment made me change the answer. He's got a valid point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be why you need 5 people agreeing on that the question should be closed. Some people who cast close votes are overly picky, others misunderstand the question etc. Until you have received 5 close votes, don't worry.

Since your question has been out there for many days without getting closed, it seems unlikely that it will.

However, in case some VB guru will find a duplicate of what might be a common question, your question might be closed as a duplicate for that reason.