# If it's a "famous question" with a "great answer", why can just 5 people decide to close it?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I was mightily surprised by how well my answer to this question was received: [Why is '१२३' numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148683/why-is-%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%A9-numeric).

Whilst it hasn't been closed yet, there are 3 close votes on it. It seems strange to me that 5 people can override the people who upvoted the question or answer - especially as the close votes seem dubious at best:

- One duplicate vote for a question about Python strings' `isnumeric` method (whereas the question is about Apache Commons in Java);
- Two for off-topic/questions about general computing hardware and software.

Of course, the close votes must have come from users with 3000+ rep, whereas the upvotes may have come from users with just 15+ rep.

I hope this doesn't come across as a case of pre-emptive sour grapes; I just think the possibility of closure/deletion seems somewhat out-of-kilter with the opinion of the community.

Comment: And another 5 people can then vote to re-open it.

Comment: First time on Meta? [Voting works differently here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Not judging the question in question with this statement, but popularity != "should be open".

Comment: The close votes there are horribly wrong. The duplicate vote is for another language, and the question is about the behavior of a specific library in a specific language, not general computing. But generally, upvotes are a good measure of usefullness in most cases, but not a good measure of on-topicness. People can like things, or think things are useful, when those things are off-topic

Comment: "upvotes are not a good measure of on-topicness" Agreed. But by the same token, the users who close voted as off-topic don't seem to have a good measure of it either.

Comment: Voting is not very surprising (also very sad) - there are plenty of people who don't even know that there are upper case letters judging by average SO post, expecting average visitor to know that there are non-Latin letters is stretch already... and definitely completely outside of reality to expect people to know about non-Western-Arabic digits.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree there. In this case it seems off. However, we hope that in most cases it is not so. There is no "fix" for bad reviewing or close voting. The only way to negate this is to educate said users on a case by case basis. There are chat rooms with users who can help moderate in cases such as this.

Comment: I saw those close votes too and they are _completely_ off. But I would be amazed to see 2 more votes come in, and I'm pretty sure it would be reopened very fast if it happens (hopefully anyway). Now, questions with lots of upvotes can gain legitimate 5 close votes, this is often the case with old resource requests or highly subjective questions that gathered votes along the years, so presence of votes does not necessarily tie with illegitimate close votes, and questions that are / used to be famous can be closed, but this isn't even remotely the case here.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't believe educating users is possible - the linked answer is a good example - it simply re-reads documentation OP linked to... Since SO relies on ability of users to read provided text I see no way how such "education" on SO can be effective... (not even sure if I'm joking here).

Comment: Well, don't panic.  With well over 10000 views, you'll always encounter some users that think your answer is great and nobody needs to post another one.  And if it does get closed then there will be plenty more views and users that think it means it might get deleted, so they'll vote to re-open.  Keep that glass half-full :)

Comment: Is this question about this specific SO post, or are you legitimately looking to start a discussion on how many users it should take to close a question?

Comment: @Travis the latter. I don't know of other examples though :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287163/why-are-so-many-useless-questions-ranked-highly-and-vice-versa)

Comment: If your goal is to have a discussion about the current minimum close vote requirement, you could have done a better job of not making it about a specific question. As far as the discussion about minimum close votes goes, good luck, I vote to leave it the way it is.

Comment: @Alexei [No one will read this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/treating-user-myopia/)

Comment: @gnat why do you close-vote as duplicate with that question eight minutes after the OP acknowledged this question is to _"start a discussion on how many users it should take to close a question?"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster because "opinion of the community" on [meta-tag:hot-questions] is worthless (and this question was in HNQ for quite a while). See  [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/): "these posts... truly start to drown out everything else on the site... it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power..."

Comment: @gnat I don't see how that answers a question like _"Should popular questions still be allowed to be closed by just five people?"_. I do understand that the question _became_ popular because it was in that list, but it doesn't seem that is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @CodeCaster so, it's not a "famous question with a great answer" anymore but just "popular", right? Duplicate answers that - no matter how popular it is, it can be useless, popularity is not a reason to make closing it harder

Comment: First time on meta. Voting works if the post is a feature request.  "http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself." http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617 The powers that be are powerless but may remain hopeful as the whats meta help topic has not been changed.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName, Luke, please stop robo-reviewing on Meta Without reading the comments. The original close-voter even admitted that the duplicate target may not apply to this question.

Comment: @Makoto I have rolled back your title change because your edit doesn't actually express what I am asking about: it's not that I think that the question is well-written, it is that *sufficient people have upvoted the question for it to have earned a famous question badge* (and, to a lesser extent, because it's questions that are closed, not answers, that sufficient people have upvoted answers to have earned a "great answer" badge).

Comment: @AndyTurner:  I'm fine with you rolling back the change, but I think you need to pick a better title.  The fame of a question factors little into group moderation, and from the premise I had originally read, it seemed that the question was objective, on-topic and clear (even if it was a duplicate).   The title is what was getting a lot of negative attention towards this question, or was my thought process about 8 hours ago.

Comment: @gnat "so, it's not a "famous question with a great answer" anymore but just "popular", right" This is SO's nomenclature, not mine - your implication is that these badges are incorrectly named: "popular question" and "popular answer" then seem more appropriate. But if popularity is not a measure (or at least a proxy) of quality, why is it called out with a badge?

Comment: that's a good question. I think badges are named appropriately and they work just fine in regular questions that gain recognition organically, it's just that HNQ advertising [distorts their meaning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283851/165773): "The way it currently works, HNQ undermines the whole way the reputation and badge system works..." To avoid misunderstanding, I do not mean to say that this particular question or answer are bad, only that votes and views on these can't be considered an indication of quality (unfortunately)

Comment: @gnat I think that answer basically nails the origin of the problem here. Honestly, I didn't think that the question was great; nor did I think my answer was great, really - any fool can copy documentation (it helps if you know the right documentation to copy, though).

Comment: wrt amount of close votes, see [Why are 5 close votes required?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261746/why-are-5-close-votes-required) "Why not 3 or 4? Why not 6? Is there empirical evidence that 5 is the correct number..."

Answer (score 19):

I do understand that on a daily basis people realize that there are in fact other [scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unicode)) besides [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script), and that numbers in those scripts can be expressed through other [glyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) than 0-9, and that their mind is blown, resulting in an upvote on the question. Working with text *is* a fascinating aspect of programming.

But what on earth happened to that question? I saw it come by in the newsletter as well. I guess it's just as random as getting a post to the Reddit frontpage: it doesn't matter if it's the umpteenth repost of the same picture, if you hit the timing just right, it'll yield you so much sweet karma.

It *is* however the umpteenth version of *"Why are these weird characters considered to be numbers in my [language|framework]?"*, and the answer is always the same: because the Unicode Consortium determined them to be (as long as there isn't a bug in the implementation).

So while the *"off-topic: general computing hardware and software"* close-votes are beyond ridiculous, I'm pretty sure there are quite a bit of duplicates that apply, given it's a language-agnostic problem, meaning duplicate votes with a proper duplicate target are correct.

It doesn't matter that the question was featured in the newsletter, viewed by thousands and voted on by hundreds: it should have been closed as a duplicate even before reaching that point, and we shouldn't hesitate to close it after that.

That being said, if it is in fact a *better* duplicate target than its predecessors, we could invert it: close the older ones as a duplicate of the newer one. Note that the voting, especially through the Hot Network Questions and Newsletter exposure, does not indicate quality, and I'm going to refrain from choosing which is the better one in this answer.

Comment: Aside from my obvious bias, I think that that [Why is '१२३' numeric?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40148683/3788176) is a more broadly-useful question than [StringUtils isNumeric returns true when input is “???”, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38577448/3788176). Whilst the two questions are, ultimately, asking about the same piece of documentation, I think that the latter is actually more that OP didn't realize (s)he had a browser rendering issue than asking why those particular symbols are considered numbers. So I'd agree with inverting that duplicate.

Comment: I've now inverted the duplicate.